# How to use nested queries with FOQElasticaBundle for Symfony2

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

I have a problem with query building with FOQElasticaBundle

I have 3 entities

- User
- Hotel
- Ambiance

Users can have 1 or more Hotels, and each Hotel has only 1 Ambiance.
In my config file, I have:

```
foq_elastica:
clients:
    default: { host: %elasticsearch.host%, port: %elasticsearch.port% }
indexes:
    MyBundle:
        client: default
        finder:
        types:
            user:
                mappings:
                    id:
                        boost: 10
                        analyzer: fr_case_analyzer
                    name:
                        boost: 5
                        analyzer: fr_case_analyzer
                    hotels:
                        type: "nested"
                        properties:
                            name:
                                boost: 10
                                analyzer: fr_case_analyzer
                            ambiance:
                                boost: 1
```

I want to be able to search for User by typing his name or the name of his hotels, and possibly add a filter on the Ambiance type.
So the query should look like something like this :

```
$mainQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Bool();
$nameQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Bool();
$filtersQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Bool();


//searching in Users' names
$nameQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Text();
$nameQuery->setFieldQuery('name', $searchName);
$nameQuery->setFieldParam('name', 'boost', 5);
$nameQuery->setFieldParam('name', 'type', 'phrase_prefix');

//searching in Hotels' names
$hotelNameQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Text();
$hotelNameQuery->setFieldQuery('name', $searchName);
$hotelNameQuery->setFieldParam('name', 'boost', 3);
$hotelNameQuery->setFieldParam('name', 'type', 'phrase_prefix');

$nestedHotelNameQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Nested();
$nestedHotelNameQuery->setPath('hotels');
$nestedHotelNameQuery->setQuery($hotelNameQuery);

$nameQuery->addShould($nameQuery);
$nameQuery->addShould($nestedHotelNameQuery);

//if filter on ambiance
$ambianceQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Term();
$ambianceQuery->setTerm('ambiance', $arrFilters['ambiance']);

$nestedAmbianceQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Nested();
$nestedAmbianceQuery->setPath('hotels');
$nestedAmbianceQuery->setQuery($ambianceQuery);

$filtersQuery->addMust($nestedAmbianceQuery);

//adding the parameters to the main query
$mainQuery->addMust($nameQuery);
$mainQuery->addMust($filtersQuery);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and returns no result if the Ambiance filter is activated, but works perfectly if I only search with the name.

What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why it wouldn't work.
The bundle actually uses __toString() on the object.
So, instead of querying on the "id" of the ambiance, I modified my html inputs so the value is the ambiance's name.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own version of the solution :

According to the elasticsearch documentation we should implement a structure that's smilar to the json bellow :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "title": "eggs" }}, 
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "comments", 
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [ 
                  { "match": { "comments.name": "john" }},
                  { "match": { "comments.age":  28     }}
                ]
        }}}}
      ]
}}}
```

So to do this with symfony 2 and according to the FOSElasticaBundle bundle we will make the following code lines :

```
//if filter on ambiance
$ambianceQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Term();
$ambianceQuery->setTerm('ambiance', $arrFilters['ambiance']);
// We will add the the term to the query bool 
$filtersQuery->addMust($ambianceQuery)

$nestedAmbianceQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Nested();
$nestedAmbianceQuery->setPath('hotels');
// we will set the result as argument in the setQuery method.
$nestedAmbianceQuery->setQuery($filtersQuery);


// And finally we add the nested query to the main query bool through addMust. 
$mainQuery->addMust($nestedAmbianceQuery);
```

Hope that will help others.

A+

Answer (score -1):

Just had the same Problem. This works for me:

```
..
$ambianceQuery->setTerm('hotels.ambiance', $arrFilters['ambiance']);
..
```

Coudn't find any examples on this in FOQElasticaBundle (now FOSElasticaBundle) for Symfony2 but it should end in an elasticsearch query like this one here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-query/

One can do/test raw elasticsearch queries like this:

```
$queryString = '{..JSON..}';
$boolQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Builder($queryString);
```